# Null object pattern with Eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There is often the case where an certain eloquent model's relation is unset (i.e. in a books table, `author_id` is null) and thus calling something like $model->relation returns null.

E.g. say a Book model has an author() (hasOne) relation I might want to do

```
$author = Book::find(1)->author->name;
```

If Book 1 has no author set it will throw a "trying to get property of non object" error. Is there a way to avoid this and default to a blank `Author` so I'll always be able to call `name` on it regardless of whether the relation has been set for the specific model?

Essentially I want to avoid conditionals to check if `$book->author` is an actual `Author` before calling further methods/properties on it. It should default to a new Author instance if the relation isn't set.

---

I tried something like:

```
public function getAuthorAttribute($author)
{
    return $author ?: new Author;
}
```

however this doesn't work; `$author` is being passed in as null, even if it's set on the model. Presumably because it's a relation rather than a direct property of a book. I'd need something like

```
public function getAuthorAttribute()
{
    return $this->author()->first() ?: new Author;
}
```

which seems pretty inelegant and seems like it would override any eager loading resulting in poor performance.

Comment: You could implement one of PHP's magic methods to fabricate default values for some fields. You'd be better of to define an array `authors` though, because a book can have multiple authors. This doesn't work for other fields though.

Comment: I'm using this as a simple example. Assume a book has one author

Comment: Using magic methods can do the job, just read the docs to get an idea how.

Comment: That's the idea of the `get<fooattribute>Attribute()` which mutates the property. However I'm pretty sure my implementation above overrides any eager loading as it needs to query the relation each time.

Comment: @harryg Did you find an elegant solution? I recently had to refactor my logic and now it allows similar scenarios... so I'm facing huge loads of code where I haven't checked anything that are now throwing errors because of empty relations and I really just want the accessed attributes to return null instead of throwing an exception. Did you manage to come up with anything?

Answer (score 8):

## Update

As of Laravel 5.3.23, there is now a built in way to accomplish this (at least for `HasOne` relationships). A `withDefault()` method was added to the `HasOne` relationship. In the case of your `Book`/`Author` example, your code would look like:

```
public function author() {
    return $this->hasOne(Author::class)->withDefault();
}
```

This relationship will now return a fairly empty (keys are set) `Author` model if no record is found in the database. Additionally, you can pass in an array of attributes if you'd like to populate your empty model with some extra data, or you can pass in a Closure that returns what you'd like to have your default set to (doesn't have to be an `Author` model).

Until this makes it into the documentation one day, for more information you can check out the pull requests related to the change: [16198](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16198) and [16382](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/16382).

At the time of this writing, this has only been implemented for the `HasOne` relationship. It may eventually migrate to the `BelongsTo`, `MorphOne`, and `MorphTo` relationships, but I can't say for sure.

---

## Original

There's no built in way that I know of to do this, but there are a couple workarounds.

## Using an Accessor

The problem with using an accessor, as you've found out, is that the `$value` passed to the accessor will always be `null`, since it is populated from the array of attributes on the model. This array of attributes does not include relationships, whether they're already loaded or not.

If you want to attempt to solve this with an accessor, you would just ignore whatever value is passed in, and check the relationship yourself.

```
public function getAuthorAttribute($value)
{
    $key = 'author';

    /**
     * If the relationship is already loaded, get the value. Otherwise, attempt
     * to load the value from the relationship method. This will also set the
     * key in $this->relations so that subsequent calls will find the key.
     */
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations)) {
        $value = $this->relations[$key];
    } elseif (method_exists($this, $key)) {
        $value = $this->getRelationshipFromMethod($key);
    }

    $value = $value ?: new Author();

    /**
     * This line is optional. Do you want to set the relationship value to be
     * the new Author, or do you want to keep it null? Think of what you'd
     * want in your toArray/toJson output...
     */
    $this->setRelation($key, $value);

    return $value;
}
```

Now, the problem with doing this in the accessor is that you need to define an accessor for every hasOne/belongsTo relationship on every model.

A second, smaller, issue is that the accessor is only used when accessing the attribute. So, for example, if you were to eager load the relationship, and then `dd()` or `toArray`/`toJson` the model, it would still show `null` for the relatioinship, instead of an empty Author.

## Overriding Model Methods

A second option, instead of using attribute accessors, would be to override some methods on the `Model`. This solves both of the problems with using an attribute accessor.

You can create your own base `Model` class that extends the Laravel `Model` and overrides these methods, and then all of your other models will extend your base `Model` class, instead of Laravel's `Model` class.

To handle eager loaded relationships, you would need to override the `setRelation()` method. If using Laravel >= 5.2.30, this will also handle lazy loaded relationships. If using Laravel < 5.2.30, you will also need to override the `getRelationshipFromMethod()` method for lazy loaded relationships.

**MyModel.php**

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Handle eager loaded relationships. Call chain:
     * Model::with() => Builder::with(): sets builder eager loads
     * Model::get() => Builder::get() => Builder::eagerLoadRelations() => Builder::loadRelation()
     *     =>Relation::initRelation() => Model::setRelation()
     *     =>Relation::match() =>Relation::matchOneOrMany() => Model::setRelation()
     */
    public function setRelation($relation, $value)
    {
        /**
         * Relationships to many records will always be a Collection, even when empty.
         * Relationships to one record will either be a Model or null. When attempting
         * to set to null, override with a new instance of the expected model.
         */
        if (is_null($value)) {
            // set the value to a new instance of the related model
            $value = $this->$relation()->getRelated()->newInstance();
        }

        $this->relations[$relation] = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * This override is only needed in Laravel < 5.2.30. In Laravel
     * >= 5.2.30, this method calls the setRelation method, which
     * is already overridden and contains our logic above.
     *
     * Handle lazy loaded relationships. Call chain:
     * Model::__get() => Model::getAttribute() => Model::getRelationshipFromMethod();
     */
    protected function getRelationshipFromMethod($method)
    {
        $results = parent::getRelationshipFromMethod($method);

        /**
         * Relationships to many records will always be a Collection, even when empty.
         * Relationships to one record will either be a Model or null. When the
         * result is null, override with a new instance of the related model.
         */
        if (is_null($results)) {
            $results = $this->$method()->getRelated()->newInstance();
        }

        return $this->relations[$method] = $results;
    }
}
```

**Book.php**

```
class Book extends MyModel
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. Your second method looks like the best option. It would be nice to have this out of the box (or at least configurable). Is there any reason why one can't implement it via a trait rather than an extra bit of class inheritence? E.g. `trait givesNullRelations { /** method overrides go here **/ }`

Comment: @harryg Yeah, it would be nice. You could always submit an issue to Laravel and see what they say. :) But, a trait would work just fine, as well. I like that idea.

Comment: @harryg I know this is over a year old, but while working on something else, I found something that was just recently added to Laravel that solves this issue. I have updated my answer with the information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my project. In my views there's some rows that are accesing to dinamics properties from null relationships, but instead of returning an empty field, the app was thrwoing and exception.

I just added a foreach loop in my controller as a temporal solution that verifies in every value of the collection if the relationship is null. If this case is true, it assigns a new instance of the desire model to that value.

```
    foreach ($shifts as $shift)
    {
        if (is_null($shift->productivity)) {
            $shift->productivity = new Productivity();
        }
    }
```

This way when I access to `$this->productivity->something` in my view when the relationship is unset, I get a empty value instead of an exception without putting any logic in my views nor overriding methods.

Waiting for a better solution to do this automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using model factories.

Define an author factory inside your ModelFactory.php

```
$factory->define(App\Author::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->firstName, //or null
        'avatar' => $faker->imageUrl() //or null
    ];
});
```

add values for all the needed attributes I am using dummy values from Faker but you can use anything you want.

Then inside your book model you can return an instance of Author like this:

```
public function getAuthorAttribute($author)
{
    return $author ?: factory(App\Author::class)->make();
}
```

Comment: Instantiating a new model is not the problem and using a model factory for getting empty model is pointless vs just doing `new Author`.  My question was on the logic required to have Eloquent automatically give me a new model instead of null when a relationship isn't set.