# Auto one-to-one model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In Django there is a concept of an "Auto one-to-one" where when you create the parent, the child relationship is automatically added as well, usually with default or null values. This can be incredibly useful because you never have to wonder if the relationship exists before you begin to interact with it.

Does Laravel have a way of doing this?

Comment: looks like none, had to be defined [explicitly](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) although you could save [several related model instance in one go](http://laravel.io/forum/06-11-2014-how-to-save-eloquent-model-with-relations-in-one-go?page=1) - might a bit outdated, just read the docs in the first link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null object pattern with Eloquent relations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085339/null-object-pattern-with-eloquent-relations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.3.23, the `HasOne` relationship added a `withDefault()` method. So, in the relationship definition on your `Parent` class, you would have:

```
public function child()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Child::class)->withDefault();
}
```

Now, when you access the `child` relationship on the parent, if there is no child record, you will get a new instance of the `Child` model instead of `null`.

You can also pass an array of attributes in `withDefault()` if you want your new instances to have default values populated (e.g. `withDefault(['name' => 'my child'])`).