# How to set null if relations doesn't exist?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

In Model I have:

```
public function publisher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

In template blade I try to show data `User`:

```
@foreach($announcement->offers as $key => $item)
    <img src="{{url($item->publisher->photo)}}">
@endforeach
```

The Problem is that if there is no data in the `User` table, the program crashes because I can not get the property `$item->publisher->photo`.

How to fix it?

Comment: You may want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085339/null-object-pattern-with-eloquent-relations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@if (empty($item->publisher))
    It's empty
@else
    <img src="{{ url($item->publisher->photo) }}">
@endif
```

Comment: @Daniel why not?

Comment: I would go for `$item->publisher()->exists()`

Comment: I would just do `@if($item->publisher)`, or even `{{ $item->publisher ? $item->publisher->name : "Unknown Publisher" }}` (if this wasn't an image that is)

Comment: @Neat `$item->publisher->exists()` would also return an error, as you cannot call `exists()` on `null`.

Comment: Of whoops, had to be `$item->publisher()->exists()`

Comment: @Neat Pretty sure that would be running another query; if you've got the property set already (`publisher`), seems inefficient to run another query to check if it exists (`publisher()->exists()`).

Comment: Still worth mentioning, also @AlexeyMezenin make that `!empty` :)

Answer (score -1):

Working on memory here, but you could use @forelse/ @empty. These directives can be used if the object your'e iterating over is empty:

```
@forelse($announcement->offers as $key => $item)
    <img src="{{url($item->publisher->photo)}}">
@empty
    //default image or message?
@endforelse
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. This is only checking if the `$announcement->offers` is empty, and not the `ithem->publisher`.